# What does the "bypass" light on a Riverbed Steelhead 200 indicate?

Tags: wide-area-network

The bypass light is on (green)

The only other light that is on is the power light (green).

I've connected the LAN port to our LAN but am not getting any link lights.

Can anyone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These kind of devices tend to go into a bypass mode if there's an issue with the device (physical or logical) so they don't interrupt your traffic flow

You may firstly want to take a look at your cabling, then your port configurations